# Making charts on phonegap using data from external website

Tags: hyperlink, phonegap

so i need to develop an app using phonegap that creates a graphical display of solar wind data (exciting stuff i know...) from this website http://services.swpc.noaa.gov/text/ace-swepam.txt with a graph being made for 'ion temperature', 'bulk speed' and 'proton denisity' individually, however im clueless as to where to begin... im assuming i need to make use of the charts.js library or something similar, im assuming i can make a variable for the axis as the data will be changing over time but I'm more stuck on how to pull data from this website though to be included in my charts. Any info on this would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,
Gerrit

Answer (score 0):

Call the web service to get the data, then pass it to the charting library you're using. You'll use AJAX (XMLHTTPRequest) to get the data. There's all sorts of options out there for simplifying this (jQuery and other libraries make AJAX easy).

The service you're using is giving you the data as a text file - this can work, but you'll have to parse the data client-side which is not fun (or a good use of your phone's capabilities). Look for a service that returns the data as a JSON object, then you'll have the data in a format that can be more easily passed to the charting library.